# Kafka Streams application on AWS ECS

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-ecs, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to run stateful Kafka-streams application on AWS ECS with multiple tasks. I mount the EFS volume on the tasks to persist the state store. It works fine for initial deployment, but it doesn't go well with restarts and rolling updates.

As this requires the state store to be maintained during restarts and rolling update, it is a challenge to assign the state store static to a particular task. Whenever a rolling update happens new tasks are created and the rebalance takes long time.

Also it is not possible to set the 'group.instance.id' with a constant value like ipaddress, hostname etc. Two tasks may run on the same host at some time.

I understand containers are ephemeral, using EC2 will be the right solution for this. But keen to know if any other options are custom solutions available to deploy Kafka streams on ECS.

Any one has deployed Kafka streams application on ECS and successfully  and handled restarts and rolling updates without any issues. Please suggest.

Comment: EKS can also be used, therefore containers will work fine, if configured correctly (k8s StatefulSet, specifically)

Comment: Yes EKS can be used. As far as I understand ECS does not fit this usecase.